# What might the (normalized) pair correlation function of prime numbers look like?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

You might have read about the [fortuitous meeting between Montgomery and Dyson](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/the-spectrum-of-riemannium). The background is that the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function, when normalized to have unit spacing on average, (seem to) have the pair correlation function $1-\mathrm{sinc}^2(x)$, where $\mathrm{sinc}$ is the normalized function $\sin(\pi x)/ (\pi x)$. It's still a conjecture but it has good [numerical support](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2007890).

So what about prime numbers? Let $\Sigma(x,u)$ be the number of pairs of primes $p,q\le x$ which satisfy the inequality $0\le p-q\le u\,x/\pi(x)$, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function. This inequality is chosen because multiplying primes by $\pi(x)/x$ will ensure the gaps between consecutives is exactly unity (hence they are normalized). Then what might

$$g(u)=\frac{d}{du}\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\Sigma(x,u)}{\pi(x)}\right)$$

end up looking like? This basically asks, "what is the density of normalized primes around so-and-so apart from each other?" (You can see the original Montgomery conjecture as equation 12 [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~hlm/paircor1.pdf). I've adapted it to prime numbers by essentially changing the asymptotic number of zeta zeros to the prime counting function instead.)

---

I have also posted this question on MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73101/what-might-the-normalized-pair-correlation-function-of-prime-numbers-look-like). I figured this question might be at more of a researcher's level than Math.StackExchange is used to and so would be beneficial to cross-post. MO user David Roberts informs me this is something of a malpractice, as it makes collecting answers awkward and a delay should be allowed for one site (presumably SE) to have a go at it. I'll keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: Also posted to MathOverflow.

Comment: I'd suggest keeping the MO one open and closing this one, since it already has a lot of good comments, and I think you are going to need someone pretty sophisticated to answer this.

Comment: I am voting to close since this is answered on Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73101/what-might-the-normalized-pair-correlation-function-of-prime-numbers-look-like) on MathOverflow.

The purpose of this answer is to redirect others, and also so that the question does not remain "unanswered".