# Is there a pair correlation function for primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

Montgomery's pair correlation function for the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann $\zeta(s)$ function is defined via the term $$1- \left( \frac {\sin(\pi u)}{\pi u} \right)^2$$

Does anybody know if there exists a pair correlation function for the sequence of the primes as well?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [What might the (normalized) pair correlation function of prime numbers look like?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58168/what-might-the-normalized-pair-correlation-function-of-prime-numbers-look-like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed found the answer in a cascade over [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73101/%E2%80%A6) this is back to the difference between a Gaussian unitary ensemable and a Poisson ensemble. Exciting although simple: No random matrices for primes, sure.